# if and elif repetition

Tags: python-3.x, computer-science, custom-lists

I would like to know if there is a way to make this type of code more succinct and automated so that I don't have to repeat the elif statements again and again.

ga is a list of cumulative seconds from 1 to whatever seconds I have recorded and I would like to separate every hour with the respective data frame from that hour is there a way to make this much simpler?

```
for i in range(len(ga)):
 if ga[i]<=3600:
    j.append(i)
 elif ga[i]<=7200:
    u.append(i)
 elif ga[i]<=10800:
    k.append(i)
 elif ga[i]<=14400:
    b.append(i)
 elif ga[i]<=18000:
    bi.append(i)
 elif ga[i]<=21600:
    bit.append(i)
 elif ga[i]<=25200:
    bitb.append(i)
 elif ga[i]<=28800:
    bitc.append(i)
 elif ga[i]<=32400:
    bitd.append(i)
 elif ga[i]<=36000:
    bite.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With list comprehensions:

```
r = [[idx for idx, val in enumerate(
    ga) if 3600*level < val <= 3600*(1+level)] for level in range(9)]

(j, u, k, b, bi, bit, bitc, bitd, bite) = r
```

Comment: Thank you that seems to be the easiest of solutions

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, It doesn't general solution, but base of problem, you can made creative solution.
Like the following code

```
# Put variable name in var
# These are empty lists that have already been defined
var = ["j", "u", "k", "b", "bi", "bit", "bitb", "bitc", "bitd", "bite"]
for i in range(len(ga)):
    # Finding var index base of ga[i] value.
    var_index = ga[i] // 3600
    if ga[i] % 3600 == 0 and ga[i] > 0:
        var_index -= 1
    # Add the ga index to the corresponding list
    eval(var[var_index] + ".append(" + str(i) + ")")
```

But it's better to use a dictionary instead of defining many variables. Like the following code.

```
# Define dictionary 
ch = {"j":[], "u":[], "k":[], "b":[], "bi":[],
      "bit":[], "bitb":[], "bitc":[], "bitd":[], "bite":[]}
# Dictionary keys
key = ["j", "u", "k", "b", "bi", "bit", "bitb", "bitc", "bitd", "bite"]
for i in range(len(ga)):
    # Finding key index base of ga[i] value.
    key_index = ga[i] // 3600
    if ga[i] % 3600 == 0 and ga[i] > 0:
        key_index -= 1
    # Add the ga index to the corresponding list in the dictionary
    ch[key[key_index]].append(i)
```

Comment: Since the variables refer to lists that are being mutated in place, you could just put an extra reference to the objects in the `var` list, rather than putting variable names (or keys into a dictionary). I'd also suggest using `whatever_index = (ga[i] - (ga[i] > 0))  // 3600` to let you avoid the extra lines. If the questioner knows that `ga[i]` is always greater than zero, they could just do `-1` instead of subtracting a `bool`).